# .select(:attribute) and rank them by frequency

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-attributes

Let's say in my rails app I have 50 different `Topics`, each identified with `topic_id`. Let's also say that this following query returns 50 posts and selects `topic_id` from each.

```
Post.where(id: something).select(:topic_id)
```

How then do I rank **top 5** `topic_ids` that most often come up from this query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works, but there may be a more efficient way to do it - feel free to chime in with suggestions, I'm new!

```
[1,2,2,2,3,4,5,6,6,6,6].group_by{|x| x}.sort_by{|k,v| -v.size}[0..4][0..4].map{|arr| arr[0] }
```

Groups the values, sorts by the size of the groups, then extracts the topic_ids from the resulting arrays. Result is an array of topic_ids sorted by frequency.